# Combining features from other projects in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC application that combines a set of features from existing applications. The new application is suppose to use UI features and logic created (especially for this purpose) in the existing applications.

For that reason I wanted to create in the existing applications some kind of a "blackbox" that I will be able to drop in my new application along with a matching connection string, and it will work independently, binding data on it's own.

I thought about using partial views, but I am having trouble with passing the model data to it, since the controller of the new application should not know about the model of the existing applications.

I can not use ASP.NET WebForms, since my application should be a "postback-less" application, and ASP.NET AJAX toolkit or frameworks alike are out of the question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Katie

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom components and asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155961/custom-components-and-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533376/developing-asp-net-mvc-ui-extensions-best-approach/2534011#2534011

Answer (score 0):

[Portable areas](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx) might help.